# how the turtle "screen.onkey" module works? need to understand this piece of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

i'm studying python on "thinking python" book and i'm trying to do the exercise. at the moment i'm studying this code which is part of the chapter 4 exercises. i ran this code (it needs the "letters" module, which i have):

```
"""This module contains a code example related to

Think Python, 2nd Edition
by Allen Downey
http://thinkpython2.com

Copyright 2015 Allen Downey

License: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/
"""

from __future__ import print_function, division

import string
import turtle

"""
To use this typewriter, you have to provide a module named letters.py
that contains functions with names like draw_a, draw_b, etc.
"""

# check if the reader has provided letters.py
try:
    import letters
except ImportError as e:
    message = e.args[0]
    if message.startswith('No module'):
        raise ImportError(message +
                          '\nYou have to provide a module named letters.py')


def teleport(t, x, y):
    """Moves the turtle without drawing a line.

    Postcondition: pen is down

    t: Turtle
    x: coordinate
    y: coordinate
    """
    t.pu()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pd()


def keypress(char):
    """Handles the event when a user presses a key.

    Checks if there is a function with the right name; otherwise
    it prints an error message.

    char: string, letter to draw
    """
    # if we're still drawing the previous letter, bail out
    if bob.busy:
        return
    else:
        bob.busy = True

    # figure out which function to call, and call it
    try:
        name = 'draw_' + char
        func = getattr(letters, name)
    except AttributeError:
        print("I don't know how to draw an", char)
        bob.busy = False
        return

    func(bob, size)

    letters.skip(bob, size/2)
    bob.busy = False


def carriage_return():
    """Moves to the beginning of the next line.
    """
    teleport(bob, -180, bob.ycor() - size*3)
    bob.busy = False


def presser(char):
    """Returns a function object that executes keypress.

    char: character to draw when the function is executed

    returns: function with no arguments
    """
    def func():
        keypress(char)
    return func


# create and position the turtle
size = 20
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.busy = False
teleport(bob, -180, 150)

# tell world to call keypress when the user presses a key
screen = bob.getscreen()

for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
    screen.onkey(presser(char), char)

screen.onkey(carriage_return, 'Return')

screen.listen()
turtle.mainloop()
```

even if i haven't studied the cycles etc yet i understand the code, but what i don't understand it's this part:

```
for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
    screen.onkey(presser(char), char)

screen.onkey(carriage_return, 'Return')
```

the onkey function should get a function without argument, but in this case it takes the presser(char) function and it works. other than that i don't understand if the onkey can bind infinite function to it. that "for" cycle basically attach every character of the alphabet to the onkey, so does onkey keep track of all function that i pass as argument? i hope i explained myself

Comment: Calling `presser(char)` returns a function with 0 params that is able to call `keypress(char)` with each lowercase ASCII value. You can't pass `keypress` directly as the handler because it will be called with 0 params and won't know which key it's been bound to trigger on, hence the extra function wrapper, effectively binding each `char` to the handler.

Comment: The thing that I don't understand is the "for" loop. Basically, it binds every character of the alphabet to onkey(), so does this means that onkey() can have multiple bindings at the same time?

Comment: Yes, the second argument to `onkey` is the key it's bound to. So this binds each lowercase key to its own handler. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkey)

Comment: Also worth mentioning: the function acts as a closure over the loop variable `char`, ensuring the correct binding and avoiding a bug where the last character in the loop is used for all `keypress(char)` calls.